# Blending NSMutableArray randomly?

Tags: objective-c

I want to shuffle the objects in the `NSMutableArray` randomly so objects from `index 1` will go to x, and move on all `array` like that .
Is there a built in function for that? (i know they have a lot ordering functions) .
If using my own algorithm , can it done without the use of other array ? i was looking for a simple way because i have lots of them to blend .

if i do something like that  :

```
 [array insertObject:[array objectAtIndex:arc4random()%arraysize] atIndex:arc4random()%arraysize];
```

i will miss objects i think..

Thanks .

Comment: I don't get what you want. Do you want to shuffle the array?

Comment: Then search for NSArray + shuffle and I'm sure that you will find something that helps you

Comment: oh great i just found the exchange method, thanks and sorry .

Comment: @Curnelious Then you use the `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObject:`. Also, don't write `arc4random() % arraysize`, it will introduce a bias. `arc4random_uniform(arraysize)` will be more uniformly distributed.

Comment: what does it mean bias?

Comment: @Curnelious Or skew. Or whatever. It's a defect in the uniformity of the random distribution caused by the modulus operation.

Comment: does exchange values with the same random number will not crash ? (if i get same random for both indexes so he has to replace 5 with 5 ..

Comment: i had a feeling ! i could see that the randomness is not pure and i was thinking that its my imagination ! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple code to achieve this:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < [array count]; x++) {
    int randInt = (arc4random() % ([array count] - x)) + x;
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:x withObjectAtIndex:randInt];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "when its possible"? :-)

Comment: you have to wait 8 minutes before it lets you :)